# etree Clone Node

Tags: python, xml.etree

How to clone `Element` objects in Python `xml.etree`? I'm trying to procedurally move and copy (then modify their attributes) nodes.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can just use [copy.deepcopy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) to make a copy of the element. (this will also work with lxml by the way).

Comment: That makes a copy, but it's not added to the tree. You'll need to do an `append()` or `insert()` to do that.

Answer (score 23):

A different, and somewhat disturbing solution:

```
new_element = lxml.etree.fromstring(lxml.etree.tostring(elem))
```

Comment: bahm, you just saved my life! This is really useful when replacing values

Comment: This is indeed a disturbing solution :)

Comment: Hah, love it! Indeed disturbing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a handle on the `Element` `elem`'s `parent` you can call

```
new_element = SubElement(parent, elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

Otherwise you might want to try

```
new_element = makeelement(elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

but this is not advised.

Comment: @SHiNKiROU You can compare `id(old_element)` with `id(new_element)` to see if it actually creates a different object in memory. Does this help?

Comment: As @Ming-Tang mentions, this **does not** copy the children.

Comment: This is useful when you want to copy an `Element` and its attributes, but you do not want to copy the children (for example when reconstructing a strict subtree by iterating through an element's ancestors). It is portable to *lxml.etree*, because unfortunately with *lxml.etree*, `copy.copy()` also copies children (documented, but how is this different from a deepcopy?).

Answer (score 1):

At least in Python 2.7 etree Element has a copy method:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l233

It is a shallow copy, but that is preferable in some cases.

In my case I am duplicating some SVG Elements and adding a transform. Duplicating children wouldn't serve any purpose since where relevant they already inherit their parent's transform.

Comment: For anyone using this and thinking of replacing *xml.etree.ElementTree* with *lxml.etree* in the future, note that `Element.copy()` does not exist in *lxml.etree*, and `copy.copy()` copies children too, when applied to an `lxml.etree.Element`.

Comment: Does not work either with cElementTree (Python 2.7). So prefer copy.copy()  (shallow copy) or copy.deepcopy() for code evolutivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you procedurally move through your tree with loops, you can use `insert` to clone directly ( `insert(index, subelement)` ) and tree indexing (both in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse('some_xml_file.xml')  # parse tree from xml file
root = mytree.getroot()  # get the tree root
    
for elem in root:  # iterate over children of root
   if condition_for_cloning(elem) == True:      
      elem.insert(len(elem), elem[3])  # insert the 4th child of elem to the end of the element (clone an element)
```

or for children with some tag:

```
for elem in root:
   children_of_interest = elem.findall("tag_of_element_to_clone")
   elem.insert(len(elem), children_of_interest[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting from the future:

If you want to clone the entire element, use `append`.

```
new_tree = ET.Element('root')
for elem in a_different_tree:
    new_tree.append(elem)
```

@dennis-williamson made a comment about it which I overlooked and eventually stumbled on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533808/4916945

Comment: To be clear, this will remove the element from the original tree!

Comment: @Spencer it won't remove anything.. but it will make a copy-by-reference, not a clone.  So any changes to the new element will alter the original

Answer (score -2):

For future reference.

Simplest way to copy a node (or tree) and keep it's children, without having to import **ANOTHER** library *ONLY* for that:

```
def copy_tree( tree_root ):
    return et.ElementTree( tree_root );

duplicated_node_tree = copy_tree ( node );    # type(duplicated_node_tree) is ElementTree
duplicated_tree_root_element = new_tree.getroot();  # type(duplicated_tree_root_element) is Element
```

Comment: To be clear, this is not a deep copy.  (Yes, the post says "and keep its children," but I still felt the need to test what it meant.)