# Python ElementTree Copy Node with childs

Tags: python, elementtree

I have to merge multiple XML-Files into one. Furthermore the structure of the new file is different. This is my "old" structure:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>1</c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
    </b>    
    <b>
        <c>1</c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
    </b>        
    <b>
        <c>2</c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
    </b>    
</a>
```

This should be the new one:

```
<a>
<1>
    <b>
        <c>1</c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>1</c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
    </b>
</1>
<2>
    <b>
        <c>2</c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
    </b>
</2>
```

So I need a function which can copy a b-Element and it's childs. I dont want to use for-Loops for this. Or is that the right way?

Comment: `<1/>` and `<2/>` are not valid element names.

Comment: Yeah, I messed it up. It was just for demonstartion..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [etree Clone Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005975/etree-clone-node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you really need a copy? Would reorganizing the tree be sufficient?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

list_of_files = ["tree1.xml", "tree2.xml", ...]

new_tree = ET.Element("a")
i = 1
for file in list_of_files:
  original_tree = ET.parse(file)
  sub_tree = ET.SubElement(new_tree, str(i))
  i += 1
  sub_tree.append (original_tree)
new_tree.write("merged_tree.xml")
```

Comment: Yes I need a copy, because I'll use the original xml for other stuff.

Comment: So a call to copy.deepcopy should be enough. `sub_tree.append(copy.deepcopy(original_tree))` in this case.

Comment: But how to copy without the child nodes. As `.append()` copy the node along with it child nodes. So how to make the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference.

Simplest way to copy a node (or tree) and keep it's children, without having to import **ANOTHER** library *ONLY* for that:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree;    

def copy_tree( tree_root ):
    return et.ElementTree( tree_root );

duplicated_node_tree = copy_tree ( node );    # type(duplicated_node_tree) is ElementTree
duplicated_tree_root_element = new_tree.getroot();  # type(duplicated_tree_root_element) is Element
```

Comment: What is odd with this is that for me with Python 3
I had  to do `duplicated_tree_root_element = new_tree.getroot().getroot()` because the type of what was returned by new_tree.getroot() was still "ElementTree". Did you have this?

Comment: No, i didn't. I developed this code using Python 2. I also found out that this method does not give you a REAL COPY of the tree, it just gives me a reference for that node. But it got the job done for what i needed...